# Bug in calculation function / program flow in C

Tags: c

I have made a verry simple calculation prog to teach myself C. but i have an odd bug now and would like to ask some advice.

About an hour ago i also asked help here to get rid of global variables and got some suggestions (again thanks for that).

Now i have implemented those suggestions but when i now input a diameter in the calculation it returns with a verry large and odd number for al 3 functions.
And that number is the same for all 3 functions.

I don't understand where the function is getting that number from as i define the diameter variable in the cir_user_input() (input.c) first and only call it again in getRadius(float diameter) (circlefunctions.c).  i have tried several things like pointers or make use of the EXTERN statement but that did not gave me the result that i wanted/expected. Hopefully someone can point me out on  what i do wrong here or can suggest some documentation on how to solve this?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "menu/menu.h"
#include "circle/circlemenu.h"
#include "input/input.h"

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
{
    menu();
    switch(menu_user_input())
{
    case 1:

        info_top();
        cir_user_input();
        info_bottom();
        break;

    case 2:
        system("cls");
        break;

    case 3:
        system("cls");
        break;

    case 8:
        system("cls");
        break;

    case 9:
        system("cls");
        break;

    case 0:
        return(0);

    default:
        system("cls");
        printf("\n **Wrong choice try again...**\n");
        break;
}

}
 return 0;
}
```

circlemenu.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "circlemenu.h"

void info_top()
{
    system("cls");
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
    printf(" Typ the diameter of the circle: ");
}

void info_bottom(double diameter)
{
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
    printf(" The radius = %f \n\n" , getRadius(diameter));
    printf(" The surface = %f \n\n" , getSurface(diameter));
    printf(" The outline = %f \n" , getOutline(diameter));
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
}
```

circlefunctions.c

```
#include "circlefunctions.h"
#include "../input/input.h"
#define PI 3.14

double getRadius(float diameter)
{
  double radius = diameter / 2;
  return radius;
}

double getSurface(float diameter){
   double radius = getRadius(diameter);
   return PI * (radius * radius);
}

double getOutline(float diameter){
    double radius = getRadius(diameter);
    return 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

input.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "input.h"

int menu_user_input()
{
    int number;
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    return number;
}

float cir_user_input()
{
    float diameter;
    scanf(" %e", &diameter);
    return diameter;
}
```

**edit**

I forgot to mention that im verry new to programming and im just trying to learn it myself. Some things may seem to be odd but im just trying to tackle and understand one problem at the time.

Comment: Are you really calling `info_bottom()` without passing it an argument?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and read what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Get into the habit of always requiring prototypes in scope; this will tell you about argument mismatches.

Answer (score 3):

`info_bottom();` you should  pass diameter as argument i.e. `info_bottom(diameter);`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@JerryGoyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194138/4516316) 's answer, In your main.c

```
case 1:

    info_top();
    cir_user_input();
    info_bottom();          //  here
    break;
```

In the commented line, you need to give `info_bottom()` an argument when you call it. Something like `info_bottom( diameter );` where `diameter` is a variable of type double you must declare in your main.c

If you had your compiler Warnings turned on, it should have warned you about this.

You should also make the `diameter` in

```
double getRadius(float diameter)
double getSurface(float diameter)
```

and

```
double getOutline(float diameter)
```

of type double. In other words, the arguments should be `double diameter`